# How to get the max x and min y coordinates from a 2D list in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, max, min

I have a list that looks like:

```
[[8.91636727 0.50420552]
 [1.50918535 8.43128826]
 [4.18447757 0.21850886]
 [8.82701669 8.39773898]]
```

Essentially they are x,y coordinates and I wanted to know how to get the highest x with the lowest y. (i.e. 8.91.. and 0.50..). I started with the X's and thought of doing:

```
for x,y in means:
    if x >= start:
        start = x; h = x; l = y 
    else:
        start = start
```

But was wondering how to implement this for the min of y's. 
Also my other issue is that there may be a case such as:

```
[[8.91636727 0.50420552]
 [1.50918535 8.43128826]
 [4.18447757 0.21850886]
 [**8.92701669** 8.39773898]]
```

Where the I dont neccessarily always want the highest x by itself, I want the highest x coupled with the lowest y.

Comment: How do you calculate the _highest x coupled with the lowest y_?

Comment: Given points `[[10, -1], [1, -10]]` which coordinates should be your output? You can't expect your points to always contain one point with highest x and lowest y at the same time.

Comment: I start by searching for the highest X, so the output will be ```[10, -1]```. Sometimes there may be a high value for X that doesn't have the lowest Y which is my issue.

Comment: `max` or `min` functions are not just enough in your case you need more conditions to solve the problem (probably require little statistics). for eg. If corresponding `y` of `max(x)` is not in the range of 10% of the smallest y then you can choose second-largest `x`. And to simplify the solution you can use quartile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could calculate the difference between `x` and `y` vectors. Then choose the one with with highest difference. If this isn't what you're looking for, I must worry you. What you're talking about is multi-objective optimization. You must clearly define, what you mean by an element with highest `x` and lowest `y`. If you cannot put it into single function, it's fundamentally impossible to take that one element. You'd have to calculate your pareto front and take one element by hand from there.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

This is one approach using `max`.

**Ex:**

```
data = [[8.91636727, 0.50420552], [1.50918535, 8.43128826], [4.18447757, 0.21850886], [8.82701669, 8.39773898]]
print(max(data, key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1])))
```

**Output:**

```
[8.91636727, 0.50420552]
```

Comment: It's just sorting the elements, first by `y`, then by `x`. It won't tell you the relation between the two.

Comment: No, that's as much as you can do to solve this problem, first find highest `x` value then lowest `y`, just as OP requested.

Comment: Neat approach but not what I was entirely looking for, this method applied to my second example gives ```[8.92701669, 8.39773898]``` which is not the lowest y.

Answer (score 0):

My final approach was:

```
li = []
difference = 0
for x,y in means:
    dif = x - y
    if dif >= difference:
        difference = dif; h = x; l = y 
    else:
        difference = difference
```

Comment: `for` loops are rather slow. Calculate difference with a single line of code: `diff = x - y`.

Then you can use [argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) method.

Comment: You should check this [guide](https://realpython.com/numpy-array-programming/).

Answer (score 0):

For people who wants max and min coordinates

```
coors= [[8.91636727, 0.50420552], [1.50918535, 8.43128826], [4.18447757, 0.21850886], [8.82701669, 8.39773898]]

max_xy = max(coors, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
min_xy = min(coors, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
```